# java, having a hard getting my print class to print my other class information, please help these are my codes

Tags: java

```
// my first class
public class FirstProject{
int first_number;

public FirstProject(){
    first_number = 0;
}
public FirstProject(int Fn){
    first_number = Fn;
}
public void Print(){
    System.out.println("First number = " + first_number); System.out.println();
}
```

}

//second class in a separate file
// keep getting an error on this class saying that cannot find the . in p1.print();

```
public class TestProgram {
public static void main(String[] args){

    FirstProject p1 = new FirstProject(10); 

    p1.print(); System.out.println();



}
```

Comment: Aren't you using an IDE?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Java is case-sensitive:

```
p1.Print();
```

But better change

```
public void Print(){ -> public void print(){
```

Since methods should not start with a capital letter, according to conventions.

Comment: i tried, it said i have to wait for 6min

Answer (score 0):

That is simply because you created it as `public void Print` and are calling it as `print`. Java is case sensitive ;)